# Why can't Python import Image from PIL?

Tags: python, importerror, python-import, python-imaging-library

The single line that I am trying to run is the following:

```
from PIL import Image
```

However simple this may seem, it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\2014-10-22_12-49.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 29, in <module>
    from PIL import VERSION, PILLOW_VERSION, _plugins
ImportError: cannot import name 'VERSION'
```

In case that's helpful, I installed pillow from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.6.1 (file `Pillow-2.6.1.win-amd64-py3.4.exe`) before running this (before that there was already som `PIL` install, which I uninstalled). The script is run in Pyzo with Python version 3.4.1.

What is going wrong, how can I import `Image`?

Comment: perhaps try a reinstall? Or have a look int the Image.py source and you might see what's causing the issue..

Comment: @Totem Tried the reinstall, did nothing. I do see the line (29) in the source, but have no idea how it causes an issue.

Comment: Can you check that `C:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py` contains constants like `VERSION`, `PILLOW_VERSION` etc? For the record, my `__init__.py` is 58 lines long, same (2.6.1) Pillow version.

Comment: @Evert Lines 14 and 15 are `VERSION = '1.1.7'` and `PILLOW_VERSION = '2.6.1'`, these seem to be the only constants. 58 lines here as well.

Comment: Then I think it's likely python still picks up another `PIL` on your `PYTHONPATH`. Try something like `python3.4 -c "import PIL; print(PIL.__file__)"`.

Comment: @Evert Running `import PIL; print(PIL.__file__)` in Pyzo gives `C:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py`. That's what it's supposed to be, right? CMD doesn't recognise the `python3.4` in front of it btw.

Comment: Looks ok indeed; I can't think what's wrong, unless it's Pyzo messing around, but I don't know Pyzo. The `python3.4 -c` part was just copy-paste from my cmdline, no worries.

Comment: Can you run the script outside of your Pyzo environment?

Comment: @Evert Running it in IDLE, I get an error instead of the path: `ImportError: No module named PIL`.

Comment: In IDLE, it's just a `PYTHONPATH` issue. But you should really try from the command prompt, provided you've set your PYTHONPATH correctly before that.

Comment: @Evert Pardon my stupidity, but what should be typed into the command prompt then? And how can one 'set' PYTHONPATH?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because installation questions are off-topic. [Can I ask questions about installation in SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338203/can-i-ask-questions-about-installation-in-so) Software tools commonly used by programmers and is
**a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.**

Answer (score 73):

I had the same error. Here was my workflow. I first installed PIL (not Pillow) using

```
pip install --no-index -f https://dist.plone.org/thirdparty/ -U PIL
```

Then I found Pillow and installed it using

```
pip install Pillow
```

What fixed my issues was uninstalling both and reinstalling Pillow

```
pip uninstall PIL
pip uninstall Pillow
pip install Pillow
```

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall fixed it for me too with pip3. Really strange...

Comment: Thanks! You saved me after 2 hours of trying to solve this error.

Comment: Actually just the first row fixed my problem. The GAE (in app.yaml) required PIL not Pillow. Thank you.

Comment: `pip install Pillow` was enough in my case, thanks!

Comment: I get the following error which is too big to post here but can be found here `https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/issues/171`

Comment: `uninstall` and then `install` fixed my problem

Answer (score 26):

I had the same issue, and did this to fix it:

1. In command prompt

   ```
   pip install Pillow ##
   ```
2. Ensure that you use

   ```
   from PIL import Image
   ```

`I` in `Image` has to be capital. That was the issue in my case.

Answer (score 25):

FWIW, the following worked for me when I had this same error:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall Pillow
```

Answer (score 13):

For me, I had typed image with a lower case "i" instead of Image. So I  did:

`from PIL import Image` NOT `from PIL import image`

Answer (score 12):

If you use `Anaconda`, you may try:

```
conda install Pillow
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8rLf.png)

Answer (score 7):

All the answers were great however what did it for me was a combination of uninstalling Pillow

```
pip uninstall Pillow
```

Then installing whatever packages you need e.g.

```
sudo apt-get -y install python-imaging
sudo apt-get -y install zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libjpeg-dev
```

And then using easy_install to reinstall Pillow

```
easy_install Pillow
```

Hope this helps others

Answer (score 6):

Install Pillow from Command Line:

```sh
python -m pip install pillow
```

Answer (score 3):

> The current free version is PIL 1.1.7. This release supports Python 1.5.2 and newer, including 2.5 and 2.6. A version for 3.X will be released later.

[Python Imaging Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)

Your python version is 3.4.1, PIL do not support!

Comment: This is Pillow, a fork of PIL, which supports Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu OS, I solved it with the followings commands

```
pip install Pillow
apt-get install python-imaging
```

And sorry, dont ask me why, it's up to me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

had the same error while using pytorch code which had deprecated pillow code. since PILLOW_VERSION was deprecated, i worked around it by:

Simply duplicating the _version file and renaming it as PILLOW_VERSION.py in the same folder.

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, pillow was installed with an environment.yml in anaconda

I am quickly learning that pip and setuptools must always be up to date or I will have problems. Always update these tools before installing packages.For any package import problem uninstall the package upgrade the listed tools(maybe even your base environment) and reinstall.

```
conda uninstall pillow
python -m pip install pip --upgrade
pip install setuptools --upgrade
pip install pillow
```

If using Anaconda, from the base environment first run the following before installing packages/environments:

```
conda update conda
```

Updating the base env is not required to fix this issue but is a good practice to avoid similar problems

@theeastcoastwest touched on the pip upgrade in their answer but I felt more information was needed

Answer (score 1):

If you've got different Python versions, be sure to install it with the version, you start the script:

```
python3.9 -m pip install pillow --upgrade
```

After a lot of googling and different solutions, this is the most efficient, I found.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing same error, just try to uninstall and resinstall

```
#uninstall and resinstalltion cmds
pip uninstall pillow
pip uninstall PIL
pip install pillow
```

Pillow installation [link](https://github.com/rabiyulfahimhasim786/opencv-basics/blob/main/basic.ipynb) basics [link](https://github.com/rabiyulfahimhasim786/opencv-basics/blob/main/images-scrapping.ipynb)

Using jupyter note book do this below follwing installationa and verified the code as shown below

```
pip install pillow

#(or)

pip install PIL

import PIL
print(PIL.__version__)

'8.4.0'
```

(Or) You are using command prompt installation then follow below instruction for windows. Personally suggest this below method.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1348]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

>pip install pillow
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (9.0.0)

>python
Python 3.10.1 (tags/v3.10.1:2cd268a, Dec  6 2021, 19:10:37) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PIL
>>> (PIL.__version__)
'9.0.0'
>>> quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

do `from PIL import Image, ImageTk`

Answer (score 0):

If you did all and it didn't work again like mien, do this
copy **Image.py** and **ImageTk.py** from **/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL** on ubuntu and **C:/Users/yourComputerName/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Lib/PIL** on windows to your projects directory and just import them!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to change the PYTHONPATH, rather than copy these files?

Comment: only this lib didn't work. The other lib could not be used after that!

Answer (score 0):

Any library/package you import must have its dependencies and subordinate parts in the same python directory. in linux if you

`Python3.x -m pip install <your_library_name_without_braces>`

what happens is, it  installs on the default python. so first make sure that only 1 python 2.x and 1 python 3.x versions are on your pc.

**If you want to successfully install matplotlib**
you need these lines,

```
python -m pip install matplotlib pillow numpy pandas
```

the last 2 were auxiliary libs, and must have.

Answer (score 0):

what that worked for me:

go to the fodler

```
C:\Users\{YOUR PC USER NAME}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages
```

and either delete or change the name of the PIL folder and DONE.

had to do it after running

```
pip uninstall PIL
```

as other suggested yielded for me

```
WARNING: Skipping PIL as it is not installed.
```

But I am not sure about the consequences of removing that library so I will edit this post if I ever get into a problem because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I actually did some debugging with my brother and found that Pillow (PIL) needed to be initialized. I don't know how to initialize it, so you could probably stick with reinstalling Pillow.

Answer (score -5):

Try `import PIL` instead of `from PIL import image`.

Comment: from PIL import Image not image