# pytesser giving import error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to implement OCR in python. When I run the following code:

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesser import *

image_file = 'menu.jpg'
im = Image.open(image_file)
text = image_to_string(im)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file, graceful_errors=True)
print "=====output=======\n"
print text
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Python27/ocr.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pytesser import *
  File "C:/Python27\pytesser.py", line 6, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Image
```

I have a folder name `pytesser` in my `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` directory
and also one named `PIL` in the same directory which is from the installation of PILLOW.

Edit: I tried the solution at [Why can't Python import Image from PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505958/why-cant-python-import-image-from-pil). But it doesn't seem to help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't Python import Image from PIL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505958/why-cant-python-import-image-from-pil)

Comment: Thanks. I tried the method mentioned there. However it doesn't help. I guess pytesser is having problem integrating with PIL. Not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the traceback, error is not from `pytesser` in `c:\Python27\Lib\Site-Packages`, it is coming from `C:\Python27\pytesser.py line 6`

Can you share the code at C:\Python27\pytesser.py line 6? or debug it by looking at code at `C:\Python27\pytesser.py line 6`

If you want your ocr.py to use pytesser at C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages (if it exists), please remove pytesser.py from the directory of ocr.py

If it is coded by you, ideally it should be `from PIL import Image`, not `import Image`

Comment: I tried opening the  file `pytesser.py` in `C:\Python27\pytesser.py`. It is a Compiled Python File and shows the same error on opening.

Comment: Do you mean you cannot open it?

Comment: I double-clicked it and the python command line flashes and reads the same error `ImportError: No module named Image`

Comment: Do not double click. Right click on the file and open it in some text editor (notepad ++, IDLE or any)

Comment: Yes. I tried that. I opened up IDLE and selected `Open`. But the file `pytesser` doesn't show in the browser. Is it because the extension is `.pyc` instead of `.py`

Comment: Yes, please open .py file of it

Comment: The .py file of it is located in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pytesser` which I edited to `from PIL import Image` but it still shows the error.

Comment: Remove pytesser.pyc from C:\Python27 and if you really need it, get new .pyc from the site-packages folder

Comment: I deleted it and now it throws `ImportError: No module named pytesser` error.

Comment: You can copy pytesser.py to c:/python27

Comment: It worked. I just copied my code file to the pytesser directory `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pytesser`