# Python PIL Module : ModuleNotFoundError : No Module named 'PIL'

Tags: python, image, import

I have a small problem. I cant use the Module 'PIL'.

After I execute my program, I get the following Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myProjektpath", line 3, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

I want to import an image in my program, and I only find the option to do this with PIL.

Comment: Have you installed ```pillow``` - ```PIL```. the command is ```pip install Pillow```. Or do you have to  python interpeters of python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505958/why-cant-python-import-image-from-pil does this help?

Comment: @Sujay i installed pillow - PIL
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (